# Tagged type : type mismatch

Tags: scala, scalaz

I try to use Tagged Type from scalaz to strengthen type safety.

I encountered a warning and an error that I don't understand.

Can you explain me both ?

Here is the output of the console :

```
scala> sealed trait PostId
defined trait PostId

scala> def PostId(l: Long) : Long @@ PostId = Tag[Long, PostId](l)
PostId: (l: Long)scalaz.@@[Long,PostId]
warning: previously defined trait PostId is not a companion to method PostId.
Companions must be defined together; you may wish to use :paste mode for this.

scala> case class Post(id: PostId)
defined class Post

scala> Post(PostId(2l))
<console>:26: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scalaz.@@[Long,PostId]
    (which expands to)  Long with AnyRef{type Tag = PostId}
 required: PostId
              Post(PostId(2l))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, `PostId` is just a tag type.
The actual tagg-**ed** type (the type that you should manipulate) is `Long @@ PostId`.

The error is that you have defined `Post` to take an instance of `PostId` when you really meant to have it take an instance of `Long @@ PostId`, hence the type mismatch.

I suggest renaming `PostId` to `PostIdTag` and defining `PostId` as an alias to `Long @@ PostId`:

```
sealed trait PostIdTag
type PostId = Long @@ PostIdTag

def PostId(l: Long) : PostId = Tag[Long, PostIdTag](l)
```

Then you can keep your `Post` definition as is.

**UPDATE**: As it turns out, scalaz tagged types seem to only work with types <: `AnyRef`, ie one cannot create a tagged type from an `AnyVal` sub-type.

The solution then is to replace `Long` with `java.lang.Long` (which works transparently because scala will automatically convert  `java.lang.Long` values to `Long`):

```
sealed trait PostIdTag
type PostId = java.lang.Long @@ PostIdTag
def PostId(l: java.lang.Long) : PostId = Tag[java.lang.Long, PostIdTag](l)
case class Post(id: PostId)
Post(PostId(2l))
```

Comment: <console>:21: error: illegal cyclic reference involving type PostId
           type PostId = Long @@ PostId

Comment: My bad, that should have been `Long @@ PostIdTag`, not `Long @@ PostId`. I Updated my answer.

Comment: A new error :scala> case class Post(id: PostId)
error: type mismatch;
 found   : Any
 required: AnyRef
Note: Any is not implicitly converted to AnyRef.  You can safely
pattern match `x: AnyRef` or cast `x.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]` to do so.

Comment: You're right. I tested it against scalaz 7.0.5 and I can reproduce the error. See my (new) update.