# How to make scalaz.Tagged work with class class primitive attributes?

Tags: scala, tagging, scalaz

Consider the following example:

```scala
import scalaz._

object TaggedExample {
  sealed trait Test

  def Test[A](a: A): A @@ Test = Tag[A, Test](a)
}

case class TaggedAttribute(l: Long @@ TaggedExample.Test)
```

It will fail to compile with next reason:

```
scalac: type mismatch;
 found   : Double
 required: AnyRef
Note: an implicit exists from scala.Double => java.lang.Double, but
methods inherited from Object are rendered ambiguous.  This is to avoid
a blanket implicit which would convert any scala.Double to any AnyRef.
You may wish to use a type ascription: `x: java.lang.Double`.
```

To my understanding, it is happens due to some details in case class compiler code generation (because simple `def test(l: Long @@ TaggedExample.Test) = l` compiles just fine).

If we change case class definition to

```
case class TaggedAttribute(l: java.lang.Long @@ TaggedExample.Test)
```

compilation will succeed.

The question is: Is there a way to avoid this `scalac` error without changing type of `l` to `java.lang.Long` (which, in turn, will allow `l` to be `null` etc.)?

---

## Update

Found this [Tagged type : type mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21134510/tagged-type-type-mismatch?rq=1) question and answer to it right after posting, but still: may be there is a way to avoid use of `java.lang.*` box types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Know bug: [Compiler error when using tagged types and case classes](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5183)

**Workaround**: use box types.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out that bug. I was looking at Scalaz bugs and completely missed out Scala's own.